# Meaning of "i" in "MiB"?

Tags: ram-usage, disk-usage

I see the usage of "MiB" as measure to represent the size in Ubuntu. What does MiB stand for? In particular the "i"?

Comment: what is the difference of MB and MiB? ref https://askubuntu.com/a/36114/230288

Answer (score 120, accepted):

There are two ways (in common use) of denoting orders of magnitude to make large numbers easier to read, first you can use a power of 10.

```
10⁰ = 1
10¹ = 10
10² = 100
10³ = 1000
```

Or powers of two

```
2⁰ = 1
2¹ = 2
2² = 4
2³ = 8
```

Using these series as a base we arrive at the numbers 1000 and 1024 (10³ and 2¹⁰) for a *kilo*.

There are eight bits to a byte. So one kilobyte is 8×10³ = 8000 bits. Hard drive manufacturers use this method. In computer science, people usually use powers of two, so one kibibyte is 8×2¹⁰ = 8192 bits.

The difference only gets larger as the numbers get larger. Some have even mixed those two systems to get nice numbers to put on their packaging. This is why a 1.44MB floppy disk has neither 1.44 megabytes nor 1.44 mebibytes (they use 1024×1000).

The *logic behind the i* is that the terms are derived from the original si prefixes, kilo, mega, giga, but with the word *binary* put in in. So the *i* is the second letter of *binary*. The mnemonic for the kibibyte is "kilo binary byte", and "KiB" is pronounced "Kibibyte".

All of this is defined in the [IEC_80000 Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_80000).

Note that a mebibyte is not defined as 2²⁰, but as (2<sup>10</sup>)<sup><sup>2</sup></sup>, although they are equal. A gibibyte is (2<sup>10</sup>)<sup><sup>3</sup></sup>, a tebibyte is (2<sup>10</sup>)<sup><sup>4</sup></sup> and so on.

```
Prefix       Bytes                      Prefix       Bytes
1 Byte     = (2^10)^0 = 1               1 Byte     = (10^3)^0 = 1
1 Kibibyte = (2^10)^1 = 1024            1 Kilobyte = (10^3)^1 = 1000
1 Mebibyte = (2^10)^2 = 1048576         1 Megabyte = (10^3)^2 = 1000000
1 Gibibyte = (2^10)^3 = 1073741824      1 Gigabyte = (10^3)^3 = 1000000000
1 Tebibyte = (2^10)^4 = 1099511627776   1 Terabyte = (10^3)^4 = 1000000000000
```

Keep in mind that, *very often,* the term kilobyte is used when the author means kibibyte. The binary unit was only introduced around 1999, as Randy Orrison points out.

---

As **nealmcb** found out in the comments, there is an official policy on this:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy

In summary, this policy reminds developers to either use SI or IEC prefixes, but to never mix them. It goes on to say:

> For file sizes there are two possibilities:
>
> - Show both, base-10 and base-2 (in this order). An example is the Linux kernel: "2930277168 512-byte hardware sectors: (1.50 TB/1.36 TiB)"
> - Only show base-10, or give the user the opportunity to decide between base-10 and base-2 (the default must be base-10).

Comment: See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy

Comment: My pleasure.  I spent a bunch of time on that and the related bugs.  Thanks for a great writeup here!

Comment: Rather than "Keep in mind that, very often, the term kilobyte is used when the author means kibibyte" I would say "Keep in mind that the term kibibyte was only introduced in 1999 and before then kilobyte referred to 1024 bytes. Most documentation, software, and programmers older than 12 years will still use the original form."  Other than that, an excellent writeup. (Date from a very quick look at wikipedia, I could be off a bit or two.)

Comment: @RandyOrrison That's a myth.  "kilo-" has been used with both definitions in computing since the 1950s.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_binary_prefixes

Comment: For the curious, a 1.44 "MB" floppy has 1.47 MB or 1.41 MiB.

Comment: "So the *i* is the second letter of *binary*." That's an unsatisfying explanation.  Why the second letter?  Why not the *first*?  Wouldn't KbB, MbB, etc. be more sensible for kilo**b**inary bytes, mega**b**inary bytes, etc.?  I *presume* it's because "Kb" and "Mb" without units could be interpreted as kilobit and megabit (or even as kilobyte and megabyte).

Answer (score 12):

> What does MiB stand for? In particular the "i"?

Since no one actually answered this: "MiB" stands for "**m**egab**i**nary **b**yte", which can be abbreviated to "**m**eb**ib**yte" (though this sounds kind of stupid, and I'd rather just stick with saying "megabinary").  [See the NIST explanation.](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html)

So the "i" comes from the word "binary".

There were other proposals to abbreviate these units in the past, but they all failed to gain traction:

- κ = 1024, κ2 = 1024², κ3 = 1024³, ... (Greek letter kappa, hard to type)
- KKB = 1024, MMB = 1024², GGB = 1024³, ... (could be misinterpreted as megamegabyte = TB)
- bK = 1024, bK² = 1024², bK³ = 1024³,  ... (when proposed, many computers didn't even have lowercase)
- 1B10 = 1024, 1B20 = 1024², 1B30 = 1024³, ...
- k₂B = 1024, M₂B = 1024², G₂B = 1024³, ...

Answer (score 10):

it's an IEC standard prefix it means "by power of two"

2^10 = 1024 = Ki-

2^20 = 1048576 = Mi-

more details on

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibi-#IEC_standard_prefixes

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Answer (score 4):

They are [binary prefixes](http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/h2g2/A30560997), corresponding to the more common decimal prefixes. (That's a good article which explains the rationale well.)