# How should I display units in my application?

Tags: development, application-development

There is inconsistency in how various operating systems display file size units.  Windows shows base 2, MacOSX shows base 10.  Does Ubuntu have guidelines for this?

Comment: Related Question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22102/meaning-of-i-in-mib/22112

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ubuntu does have a [policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy) for this.  The basic gist is as follows:

Use base-10 for network bandwidth (e.g. 6 Mbit/s or 50 kB/s) and disk sizes (e.g. 500 GB hard drive or 4.7 GB DVD).  When using base-10, follow the [SI standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) for prefixes (e.g. kB, MB).

Use base-2 for RAM sizes (e.g. 2 GiB RAM).  When using base-2, follow the [IEC standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60027) for prefixes (e.g. KiB, MiB).

There is the library [libkibi](https://launchpad.net/libkibi), available starting with Ubuntu 11.04, that provides helper functions for formatting sizes appropriately.