# Is Nautilus reporting wrong free space?

Tags: 10.10, nautilus

[image]

I have 87.2 GB left as shown by PCMANFM, but Nautilus shows only 81.3 GB, why is that, i've been using SHIFT+DEL to remove files so, i don't know why is this happening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By the looks of it, Nautilus is reporting [GiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) ( = 1 073 741 824 bytes) and PCMANFM is reporting [GB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) ( = 10^9 bytes).

In other words:

81.3 GiB = 81.3 * 1 073 741 824 bytes = 87.2952103 × 10^9 bytes = 87.2 GB

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 will be using GiBs and MiBs. It is one of the features of the new version. It's something that OS/X had for the last few years.

Comment: does it make any difference? to use GiB and GB?

Comment: @user4124, no Ubuntu will be using SI-units; kB, MB, GB etc. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy

Comment: Just a matter of what standard you use, as long as you know what is being used. Computer scientist will most likely tend to work with GiB, while (for example) hardware vendors will more likely use GB because the bigger numbers make their HDD appear to have more space.

Comment: I've written a bit about how the difference comes about at [Meaning of “i” in “MiB”?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22102/meaning-of-i-in-mib/22112#22112) - may be helpful.