# ext4 partition size / free space discrepancies

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, ext4, gparted

While creating a 250GiB backup partition for my data, I have noticed lots of discrepancies between reported partition size and free space in Nautilus, gParted, df, tune2fs, etc.

At first I thought it was a GiB / GB confusion. *It was not*.

Then I thought it could be ext4's reserved blocks. *It was not*.

Im completely puzzled. Here are some images. Here are the steps:

- First, NTFS. 524288000 sectors x 512 bytes/sector = 268435456000 bytes = 268.4 GB = 250 GiB.

[image]
[image]

Nautilus say "**Total Capacity: 250.0 GB**" (even though its actually GiB, not GB). Apart from that minor mislabeling, so far, so good

- Now, *same* partition, formated as ext4 with gparted:

[image]

First, Last and Total sectors are the same. It IS the same 250GiB partition. Used size is 4.11GiB (reserved blocks maybe?)

[image]

Nope. Looks like reserved blocks are 12.7 GiB (~5%. *ouch!*). But... **why Total Capacity is now only 246.1 GiB ???**. That difference (sort of) matches the 4.11 GiB reported by gparted. But... if its not from reserved blocks, what is it? **And why gparted didnt report that 12.7GiB of used space?**

```
$ df -h /dev/sda5
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5             247G  188M  234G   1% /media/BACKUP
```

`df` matches Nautilus in reported free space. But.. only 188M used? Shouldnt it be ~12GB? And total capacity is still wrong. So i ran `tune2fs` to find some clues. (irrelevant output is ommited)

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda5
tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   BACKUP
Filesystem UUID:          613d592e-47f5-4206-96a7-210090d340ef
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Filesystem state:         clean
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Block count:              65536000
Reserved block count:     3276800
Free blocks:              64459851
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
```

65536000 total blocks * 4096 bytes/block = 268435456000 bytes = 268.4 GB = 250 GiB. It matches gparted.

3276800 reserved blocks = 13421772800 bytes = 13.4 GB = 12.5 GiB. It (again, sort of) matches Nautilus.

64459851 free blocks = 264027549696 bytes = 264.0 GB = 245.9 GiB. **Why? Shouldnt it be either 250-12.5 = 237.5 (or 250-(12.5+4.11)=~233) ?**

Removing reserved blocks:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda5
tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Setting reserved blocks percentage to 0% (0 blocks)

$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda5
tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   BACKUP
Filesystem UUID:          613d592e-47f5-4206-96a7-210090d340ef
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Filesystem state:         clean
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Block count:              65536000
Reserved block count:     0
Free blocks:              64459851
Block size:               4096
```

As expected, same block count, 0 reserved blocks, but... *same free blocks*? **Didnt I just freed 12.5 GiB ?**

```
$ df -h /dev/sda5
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5             247G  188M  246G   1% /media/BACKUP
```

[image]

Looks like I did. Avaliable space went up from 233 to 245.9 GiB. gparted didnt care at all, showing *exactly* same info! (useless to post an identical screenshot)

**What a huge mess!**

I tried to document it as best as I could... So, please can someone give me any clue on what's going on here?

- What are those misterious 4.11 GiB missing from NTFS -> ext4 formatting?
- Why there are so many discrepancies between gparted, Nautilus, tune2fs, df?
- What is wrong with my math? (questions in bold scattered this post)

Any help is appreciated. While I can not figure what is going on, I am serilously considering giving up on ext4 in favor of NTFS for everything but my / partition.

Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24371/is-nautilus-reporting-wrong-free-space

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22102/meaning-of-i-in-mib/22112#22112

Comment: @Uri Herrera: did you actually *read* my question, or at least the first few lines? This is *not* a GiB/GB issue. Partition is 268.4GB = 250.0GiB, *not* 246.1

Comment: Another answer you can take a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5335/why-is-there-4-86maybe-15-1-gb-of-used-space-on-a-newly-partitioned-and-formatt/5337#5337

Comment: See also [ext4: How to account for the filesystem space?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/ext4-how-to-account-for-the-filesystem-space)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.  gparted reports the actual used/free space.  The kernel reduces the available count by the reserved space.  After you removed the reserved space, the free count did not change because the reserved blocks already were free; it is just that non root users are not allowed to invade that space to prevent them from causing trouble by filling up the disk.  The gnome numbers are a little flaky because of a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus/+bug/571510).  Instead of reporting the used space that the kernel reports ( and df shows ), it computes it by subtracting the free space from the total.  This causes it to show reserved space as used.

The missing 4GB is actually used is the fs overhead for ext4.  NTFS only initially allocates a small amount of space for the MFT, and grows it as needed.  The ext series of filesystems though, allocate space for the inode table ( rough equivalent of the MFT ) at format time and it can not grow.  The space missing from the reported total space is the inode table.  The remaining bit of used space is from the journal ( usually 128 mb ) and resize inodes.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for solving some of the mysteries! But, if the ~4GB are filesystem overhead, why some of it (3.9GB) is deducted from total space, while 188MB is showing as actually used? Which (or both) is the overhead? And why handled differently? Also, `df`, even with sudo, shows total capacity (247GB) and used space (188MB) like Nautilus. So if its a bug, its not only gnome's.

Comment: I thought the 188MB was the overhead (as compared to the 72MB from NTFS). But, if NTFS overhead will grow after time, does that mean Nautilus would later report it's total capacity *shrinking*?

Comment: Correction: df always shows available space, no matter who runs it.  To see the free space (== available space + reserved space), use `stat -f /media/BACKUP`.

Comment: Edited answer to clarify.  And I believe that NTFS will just report more used space, not shrink total as the MFT grows.  @Marius, this is not correct either.  statfs() and hence both df and stat -f both show the available space not counting the reserved blocks.  I could have sworn that it also adjusted for quota, and varied its response based on the calling user, but you are right about that; it does not count quota and does not care what user calls it.

Comment: @psusi: so I have ~3.9GiB of inode table, and ~188MB of journal+something? And Nautilus subtract inode table from Total Size, while reports journal as used space? And gparted reports them as a single 4.11GiB of used space? Is that correct? If so, i just wished Nautilus handled both overhead the same way.. either both subtracted from total or both counted as "used space" (preferably).

Comment: @MestreLion roughly, yes.  It is actually the kernel that does not count the inode table as part of the total size, not nautilus.  Nautilus just reports what the kernel says.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, reserved blocks **are not** block used for filesystem internal management.

Reserved blocks are simply reserved for `root`, as to assure that services using files on that partition cannot be ruled out of space by some non-admin user filling all the space.

Even with no reserved blocks (`-m 0`) there is always a part of the space used for filesystem internal management, I cannot say how much, I have not such a deep knowledge.

Also, *Gparted* is executed as `root`, so it see reserved blocks as free. *Nautilus*, executed as user, see them as non free.

Ok, @psusi answer is very clear, I have nothing to add.

Comment: Humm, very informative, +1. At least this solves some of the issues I've found. Seeing reserved blocks as a "limit cap" for non-root instead of "used blocks" makes gparted, df and tune2fs readings agree (and make sense). But some questions still remain, specially the 4GB of used space / total capacity.

Comment: Also, I've read somewhere (one of those old "why you don't need to defrag your Linux partition every month" HOWTOs perhaps?) that reserving 5% space for root gives some breathing space to the extN allocation algorithms and therefore avoids fragmentation.

Answer (score 6):

After partitioning my brand new 8 TB disk with gparted, it reported:

```
  Size: 7.28 TiB
  Used: 59.76 GiB   <-- Huh?
Unused: 7.22 TiB
```

Which is why I ended up here. Now let the investigation begin.

Running `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc` (where /dev/sdc is my new disk)
reveals:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 7,3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
...
Disklabel type: gpt
```

Note that 15628053168 * 512 = 8001563222016.

From now on lets work in number of SECTORS (which are 512 bytes)
and work exclusively with hexadecimal notation. This gives us,

```
fdisk (real values)
Disk size: 3a3812ab0
```

Furthermore, fdisk gives us the partition table:

```
Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 15628052479 15628050432  7,3T Linux filesystem
```

Lets translate that into hex too (it already is in sectors):

```
/dev/sdc1    800   3a38127ff   3a3812000  7.277378082275390625 TiB
```

(That TiB value is *exact*; but in decimal. It shows why 7.3 was printed).

The first 0x800 sectors are reserved for the Master Boot Record (MBR) and
the partition table (type gpt, since it was created by gparted and I choose
to use that type there).

The `End` sector is inclusive, so indeed

```
3a38127ff + 1 - 800 = 3a3812000
```

But why was this chosen? Well, because gparted rounded everything off to 1 MiB
boundaries (it said), which happens to be 0x800 sectors (1024 * 1024 / 512 in hex).

Nevertheless, why didn't it pick 3a3812fff as last sector? Well, because that doesn't exist, the total disk size is 3a3812ab0 as we saw before.

Ok, so we need a little space at the start for MBR and parition table, but only want to start and end partitions at 0x800 boundaries, therefore the first sector is 800 and the last one is 3a38127ff. Leading to a total **partition size** of 3a3812000 sectors,
or 7.28 TiB as reported by gparted (8001561821184 bytes in decimal).

The type of the filesystem on it is ext4.

Lets start with mounting it, and lets now work in sectors in DECIMAL:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/newdisk
df -B512 | grep sdc1
/dev/sdc1 15502817864 102728 14721279848  1% /mnt/newdisk
```

So df reports, in sectors and in hex:

```
df Size: 15502817864 sectors (= 7937442746368 bytes = 7.219... TiB).
df Used: 102728 sectors (= 52596736 bytes = 50.16 MiB).
df Available: 14721279848 sectors (= 7537295282176 bytes = 6.855... TiB).
```

Hence, the reported size is 8001561821184 - 7937442746368 = 64119074816 = 59.716 GiB **less** than the partition size reported by fdisk!

Ok, so how does ext4 work?

We can quickly get a lot of information running

```
sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdc1
```

The most important output being

```
Inode count:              244191232
Block count:              1953506304
Reserved block count:     97675315
Free blocks:              1937839392
Free inodes:              244191221
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      558
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         4096
Inode blocks per group:   256
Flex block group size:    16
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal size:             1024M
Journal length:           262144
```

Note that the Block count shows the **full** partition size. One block being 4096 bytes, we have 1953506304 * 4096 = 8001561821184.

So clearly we're looking for blocks that are not available to us. Going with what `df` reports as Available (7537295282176 / 4096 = 1840159981 blocks available), that are 113346323 blocks that are not available.

The journal exists of 262144 blocks, so... 113346323 - 262144 = 113084179 blocks to go.

We have 558 reserved GDT blocks... 113083621 block to go.

The number of "groups" on the fs is 'total number of inodes' / 'inodes per group' = 244191232 / 4096 = 59617.

The inodes being 256 bytes in size account for 244191232 * 256 / 4096 = 15261952 blocks, so 113083621 - 15261952 = 97821669 blocks to go.

We're out of options here, apparently the Reserved block count isn't available either,
which is 97675315 .. so that leaves 97821669 - 97675315 = 146354 blocks that are unavailable that we didn't explain yet. That is still 571.7 MiB, or ~2.455 blocks per group, but not THAT much compared to the 59.76 GiB that we had to explain.

Running the following command:

```
cat /proc/fs/ext4/sdc1/mb_groups | sed -e 's/^#.*://' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | sed -e 's/^\(..............\).*/\1/' | grep -v free
```

We get the number (first column) of groups that have N blocks free (second column):

```
  55860  32768
   3724  28640
     22  31743
      8  0    
      1  8958 
      1  28639
      1  27609
```

Clearly the maximum of free blocks per group is 32768 (most of them), which is also what `dumpe2fs` reported (Blocks per group).

So, let me convert this table to 'Used' in bytes by subtracting the second column from 32768 and multiplying that with 4096 bytes. Then I get

```
   3724  16908288
     22  4198400
      8  134217728
      1  97525760
      1  16912384
      1  21131264
```

and 3724 * 16908288 + 22 * 4198400 + 8 * 134217728 + 97525760 + 16912384 + 21131264 = 64268140544 or 59.85 GiB.

**SUMMARY**

```
Unavailable blocks      Reason
97675315                Reserved block count (5%)
15261952                inodes (0.78%)
262144                  journal (0.013%)
146354                  Unexplained (0.007%)
558                     Reserved GDT blocks (0%)
```

Lets start with changing the reserved block count to 0, because this HDD is for long term storage and I really don't care what happens if it runs full (I do, but my system will still function perfectly).

```
sudo umount /dev/sdc1
sudo tune2fs -r 0 /dev/sdc1
```

dumpe2fs now reports:

```
Reserved block count:     0
```

but more importantly,

```
df -B512 | grep sdc1
/dev/sdc1 15502817864 102728 15502682368   1% /mnt/newdisk
```

aka

```
df Available: 15502682368 sectors (= 7937373372416 bytes = 7.22... TiB)!
```

We can also reduce the number of inodes, but that is only smart if you are sure that you won't need them; for example when you will only store large files on the disk. The number of inodes is roughly the number of files + directories you can store on the disk. So, having 244191232 will allow me to store files with an *average* size of 32kB (32504 bytes) on this disk. Instead I intent to store mostly files on it of a size of roughly 1 to 2 GB... So yeah, I think I can safely reduce the number of inodes by say a factor 10.

So, I decided to reformat my partition (screw gparted, all I needed was a partition table, not a filesystem):

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -b 4096 -e remount-ro -i 325040 -j -L '/opt/verylarge' -m 0 -t ext4 -T big -U 48c6a937-aea3-42a0-a69c-c24d0dc65179
```

After which I ended up with

```
Inode count:              24800672
Block count:              1953506304
Reserved block count:     0
Free blocks:              1951529866
Free inodes:              24800661
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         416
Inode blocks per group:   26
Flex block group size:    16
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal size:             1024M
Journal length:           262144

df -H
Filesystem  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1   8,0T   97M  8,0T   1% /mnt/newdisk
```

I have NO idea where that 1% comes from, but I'm happy with my 8,0 TB :)

Comment: What a comprehensive answer, thanks! If almost all of the originally "used" space was due to the 5% reserved space, and the overall filesystem overhead itself is merely less than 0.8% initially, I'm fine with letting the default settings alone. The reserved space is  a good "safety net" for the general user, and it's usable by root, so it should not be changed unless one _really_ knows what they're doing.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I could have saved a lot of time if there weren't so many people saying contradicting things about "reserved" space being free, only being reserved for root, and therefore NOT showing up, etc. I even read about someone who didn't see a change after using tune2fs to remove the resversed space. People saying that all of the wasted space was due to fs administration. I wanted to know the truth, and being the (famous, haha) author of ext3grep, I thought I'd just dive into ext4 and determine once and for all what this was about.

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing the partition size by a few megabytes using gparted, then increasing it again to its original size.  This may cause other applications to read the sizes correctly. I recently corrected a 50Gb error this way!