# My df totals don't come close to adding up... why?

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ext4 partition size / free space discrepancies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48488/ext4-partition-size-free-space-discrepancies)

The results from a df on my main drive on my server don't add up.  I came close to running out of disk space, I freed 4 gigs a couple of days ago, but we're still getting weird results two days later.

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             78441416  73732352    724536 100% /
```

Now, by my calculation, 78,441,416 - 73,732,352 = 4,709,064, so there should be over 4 gigs left, not the 724,536K that df is reporting.

I don't see this could be a quota error - though `quota -f` apparently isn't an option for Ubuntu and I haven't yet found a command to recompute the quota.

I'm now going through the various directories doing a `du -sk` (glad the server seems to have light traffic for a Monday morning) but not sure what that will tell me.

Any hints?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Linux filesystems routinely reserve between 1 and 10 percent of the filesystem for the root user. This is to ensure the root user can function when a non-root user "fills" the filesystem. The df command does not show this reserved space as available.

As root, run this command: `/sbin/tune2fs -l /dev/sda1`
Look for the line that reads "Reserved block count".

You can also use `tune2fs` to change the amount reserved.

Comment: Cool, I didn't even know about this place!  As you can see from my answer below, Devon's answer is correct.

Comment: Question:  how much space should one be reserving?  There were almost 5 gigs reserved - that seems an awful lot, considering the root account only appears to be using a couple of hundred meg right now... I lowered it to 2 gig, but I'm slightly worried this isn't enough, or conversely, if I could *completely* safely lower it to 1 gig, well, that's another gig in the bank.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I finally worked it out, it's a combination of things.

I knew that about 1000000 blocks were reserved for "root" - but I hadn't realized that this machine had 4K blocks (I've been doing a lot of digital audio this year so for me a "block" is 1K :-D).  So there's my 4 gig!

Now I have to figure out how to reduce somewhat the amount reserved for root, but that I can probably do quite easily...

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: `tune2fs -m <reserved-blocks-percentage> /dev/sdxx`. Note that the reserved space is used to help prevent fragmentation, so reducing it could cause performance loss. You should accept Devon_C_Miller's answer.