# SSD total capacity <> free space + used space

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, format, df

I got a new 500GB SSD and formatted it with ext4+LUKS using the *Disks* utility in Ubuntu 16.04.

1. Enter disk with Nautilus, right-click and Properties. Total capacity is 492 GB, free space is 467 GB, and used space is 73 MB. Shouldn't Total = free + used?
2. Using `df -H <mydisk>` I get the same values as nautilus. Using `df -h <mydisk>` I get total size 459GB, available 435GB, and used 70M. (Notice `-h` is powers of 1024, and `-H` is powers of 1000.)

   - `500 * 10^9 / 2^30 = 465.66 GB` meaning the total size of 459GB makes sense when using powers of 1024. However, the discrepancy between total size and available+used space is still present.

[image]

Total size of the disk is quite different from the sum of the free and used amounts. Why? [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/100212/298314)

---

This is a secondary disk. The OS is installed in a different disk.

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb 
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

$ lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME                                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                           8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk  
└─luks-<long-random-string-1> 253:3    0 465,8G  0 crypt /media/daniel/<long-random-string-2>

$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/luks-<long-random-string-1>
<this works>
```

How do I recover the reserved space? ([this](https://askubuntu.com/a/249415/298314) doesn't work)

**Edit:** I've reduced the reserved space using `$ sudo tune2fs -m 0.3 /dev/mapper/luks-<long-random-string-1>`. The problem was that I wasn't using the correct device (drive is encrypted).

Comment: You second part the command is incorrect.  You have to specify the partition or you get that failure.  `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1`

Comment: @Terrance: I don't have `/dev/sdb1`. This is an internal SSD, but appears mounted at `/media/daniel/<long-random-string>`. Using this path yields the same error.

Comment: Give the output of `lsblk /dev/sdb`.

Comment: @Terrance: Added `lsblk` output to question.

Comment: It can't read encrypted partitions.

Comment: @Terrance: The drive is mounted. It seems that `$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/luks-<long-random-string-1>` will read it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile here.  I didn't see the full mount.

Comment: @Terrance: I've managed to remove/reduce the disk space using the the `/dev/mapper/luks-...` device. Thanks for the help.