# Ubuntu12.10 "Disks" Pendrive 64GB format LUKS+ext4

Tags: usb-drive, ext4, luks, fat32

I just bought Pendrive / Flshdrive 64GB and need to archive on it file bigger than 10GB so i believe FAT32 is not an good option since it can handle only 4GB file in size. Next thing is that i though about formatting it with ext2 to avoid overwriting with journaling but when i open Disks application to format pendrive i have only option of Fat32 / Ext4 and LUKS + Ext4, and that is another thing, i need some sort of protection so how safe it will be to use ext4 + luks,

1.How does it works is the encryption AES 256?

2.It will ask me the password any time i need access the files on pendrive?

3.Why it take space on my pendrive in the lost+found folder i make test on old 2GB flashdrive ext4 + luks and it "eat" about 130mb?

4.What will happen if insert to anther linux computer?

5.What if i put it into windows with ext drivers installed, will it works asking for password?

6.Will ext4 + luks not overuse "wear" my pendrive too fast?

7.Isn't FAT32 support drive up to 32GB only? then why it let me format 64GB flashdrive?

8.Files permissions are not useful for me so how to deal with it on ext4, so that if i will use that pen drive on new or re installed system there will be no access problems?

Thank you for an answer

Comment: This is something you might be better of asking on ubuntuforums.org (that site is more about discussion) AskUbuntu works best with 1 question and a 1, 2 or more answers where you pick the one the suits you best as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

> How does it works is the encryption AES 256?

AES stands for [Advanced Encryption Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) and is considered a strong algorithm for cryptography.

> It will ask me the password any time i need access the files on pendrive?

Yes, that's the whole point of having it secured; you'll need to provide a secret to be able to read/write to it.

> Why [...] ext4 + luks [...] "eat" about 130mb?

The Linux Ext2/3/4 file system doesn't 'eat' space - this is either the filesystem overhead, or the reserved space. Similar question: [New ext4 partition and used space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131516/new-ext4-partition-and-used-space)

> What will happen if insert to anther linux computer?

Depends on the configuration of that other Linux computer. There's no single answer to this. If you need this to work on another PC, you should make sure at least `libcryptsetup`, a relatively recent Linux kernel and a capable file manager is installed.

> What if i put it into windows with ext drivers installed, will it works asking for password?

No. Besides Ext2/3/4 'drivers' for Windows, you'll need [FreeOTFE](http://www.freeotfe.org/) too.

> Will ext4 + luks not overuse "wear" my pendrive too fast?

It does not feature any optimization for flash drives. The block size of a common USB flash drive is bigger than de default dm-crypt one, so I guess it's not creating additional overhead in terms of wear levelling. However, Ext4 does journalling by default. You may want to turn that feature off at creation time.

> Isn't FAT32 support drive up to 32GB only?

No. Where did you get that information? It [supports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) volumes up to 2-16 TB (depending on the block size). As @Rinzwind [pointed out](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/format-fat32-drives-beyond-32gb-limit/5693) in his comment, Windows might be limited to accessing/formatting up tot 32 GB by default.

Comment: Windows + 32Gb: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/format-fat32-drives-beyond-32gb-limit/5693