# LVM Partition Size Discrepancy

Tags: partitioning, lvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ext4 partition size / free space discrepancies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48488/ext4-partition-size-free-space-discrepancies)

I am simply confused by some output I'm seeing.  When I run "df -h" the lines that are confusing me are as follows:

```
Filesystem                     Size   Used   Avail  Use%
/dev/mapper/sysvg-lvvideos     293G   4.5G   274G   2%
```

When I run "vgdisplay" I get:

```
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               sysvg
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        2
Metadata Sequence No  8
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                4
Open LV               4
Max PV                0
Cur PV                2
Act PV                2
VG Size               1.01 TiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              265251
Alloc PE / Size       120508 / 470.73 GiB
Free PE / Size        144743 / 565.40 GiB
VG UUID               4TjHj7-11CY-auM2-h05h-BXSV-2S4X-WUDh5R
```

When I run "lvdisplay sysvg" I get:

```
--- Logical volume ---
LV Name                /dev/sysvg/lvvideos
VG Name                sysvg
LV UUID                ZXNPP0-2IUI-UT1s-3riN-fxZH-QmfW-3OgwPI
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                293.00 GiB
Current LE             75008
Segments               2
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           254:2
```

What I don't get is: 293 - 4.5 does NOT equal 274.  I have 14.5 GiB unaccounted for.

Comment: You are right.  I could have found my answer there as well.  When I searched my issue before posting, I didn't see that one as I didn't use the right search keywords.  But thanks for pointing out the duplicity.  Reading that was very informative. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because normally 5% of the space is reserved for the root user.

you can disable that by

```
tune2fs -m0 /dev/sysvg/lvvideos
```

**EDIT**

that has nothing to do with LVM, that's a "feature" of the chosen filesystem...

**EDIT2**

The manpage of mke2fs states the following

```
   -m reserved-blocks-percentage
          Specify the percentage of the filesystem blocks reserved for the
          super-user.   This  avoids  fragmentation, and allows root-owned
          daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to  function  correctly
          after non-privileged processes are prevented from writing to the
          filesystem.  The default percentage is 5%.
```

So yes that applies to all ext2/ext3/ext4 partitions.

Comment: So, as a "feature" of that filesystem...any partition I create using ext4 is going to reserve 5% for the root user?  I ask because this result is the same for all my ext4 partitions.

Comment: Yes, check the edited answer for an explanation...

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you so much.  I was off thinking I had to change the size of my Physical Extents...I never would have figured that out.  :-)  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. If an answer is helpful you should accept it, so other users know it did actually fixed your problem...

Comment: How do I accept it?  I feel silly asking, but this is my first time here.

Comment: In general look at this: http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask

It is possible that you cannot accept this answer as the question has been closed as it is a duplicate...