# df -h - Used space + Avail Free space is less than the Total size of /home

Tags: disk-usage, ext4

As the output of `df -h` shows here, something is eating up 5GB of free space. So, it's not available to use.

I'm also noticing sometimes that the hard disk gets filled up to 100% sometimes. So, I had to restart the machine or delete some unncessary files. Only noticed these in /home partition. Don't know whether these two are related, but appreciate if anyone can put some insight into this.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8             100G   92G  2.7G  98% /home
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ext4 partition size / free space discrepancies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48488/ext4-partition-size-free-space-discrepancies)

Comment: My reason for **"leave open"** is that the "Possible **duplicate**" question is **extremely long**. Good for being informative there wile not good here as **this question is only about 1/20 as long**. Not even similar.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

By default, `ext2/3/4` filesystems reserve 5% of the space to be useable only by `root`. This is to avoid a normal user completely filling the disk which would then cause system components to fail whenever they next needed to write to the disk.

You can see the number of reserved blocks (and lots of other information about the filesystem) by doing:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda8
```

For a `/home` partition, it is probably safe to set the reserved fraction to zero:

```
sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda8
```

Which should make an additional ~5GB available.

Comment: Yep... that's what I've been looking for. Thanks

Comment: In my case it freed around 22 GB!

Comment: is its safe to set reserved size to 0 on a mounted partition ( not / )? Because I accidentally did just that

Comment: This solved my black screen issue after restoring with aptik

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil According to `man tune2fs`, "Normally, the default percentage of reserved blocks is 5%."

Comment: @Mah35h There is no warning against using `-m` on a mounted partition. It looks reasonable that such property can be changed (at least decreased) safely (otherwise it would be incorrect not to check that, so they would just forbid that action). I've just launched this command, and there were no errors and all functions normally.

Answer (score 11):

This question is really about ***interpreting the output of the `df` command***, which is famously confusing and if you Google it, you'll see many questions about `df`.

#### How to interpret `df`'s output

`Size` in `df`'s results are inclusive of the 5% reserved space [@chronitis told you about](https://askubuntu.com/a/249415/618353). This is the total *absolute* space. This number will approximate the size shown in the results of `fdisk -l` for the partition which you're reviewing in the `df` results.

`Used`+`Avail` provides the total *effective* space and *excludes* the 5% reserved space. This is the space you can actually work with.

So nothing is missing. The disparity between `Size` and `Used`+`Avail` totals in `df`'s output represents the 5% reserved space.

#### Free space not accounted for in `df`'s output

If you're scratching your head thinking *"But I deleted that file(s), why can't I see the additional space in `df`?!?"*, here's why:

If you delete a large file(s) but the process for it hasn't been terminated, this "free" space won't be reflected in the results of `df`.

`sudo lsof +L1` will identify deleted files still showing a PID.

Answer (score 5):

By default, ext2/3/4 filesystems reserve 5% of the space to be useable only by the superuser, `root`.

There is also some space reserved for **metadata**, that is necessary for the file system, for examples inodes and the journal.

You can find some details in the manual

```
man mkfs.ext4
```