# Why is there a large difference between disk use reported by system information and lsblk and reported by df / du?

Tags: 22.04, disk-usage

When I start a terminal, I see this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-165-generic x86_64)
...
System information as of jeu 26 oct 2023 11:16:34 CEST

System load:            0.45
Usage of /:             49.7% of 455.20GB
Memory usage:           50%
Swap usage:             19%
Processes:              182
Users logged in:        0

=> /bu is using 91.9% of 1.79TB
```

But when I use du or df, I get:

```
$ df
Sys. de fichiers            blocs de 1K    Utilisé Disponible Uti% Monté sur
udev                             457888          0     457888   0% /dev
tmpfs                             97128       3040      94088   4% /run
...
/dev/sdc                     1920645740 1765707476   57348560  97% /bu
...
~$ sudo du /bu
4       /bu/lost+found
1765707472      /bu
```

The results given by du and df (97% used) are identical but very different from the value given by system information (91.9% used).  Why is this?

The results (at least in %) are identical for various forms of df:

```
$ df --si
Sys. de fichiers            Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
...
/dev/sdc                      2,0T    1,9T   59G  97% /bu
$ df -H
Sys. de fichiers            Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
...
/dev/sdc                      2,0T    1,9T   59G  97% /bu
~$ df -h
Sys. de fichiers            Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
...
/dev/sdc                      1,8T    1,7T   55G  97% /bu
```

------ Edit - Results of lsbk ----
As askeh by Hannu, here is the output.  This time, FSUSE% is at 92%, conform to motd.  So, it seems the content of the 'MOTD' is based on some extraction of `lsblkid`. I updated the question title accordingly.

```
 lsblk -ap -o +MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,LABEL,PARTLABEL,FSUSE%,STATE,MODEL
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT     MOUNTPOINT     FSTYPE      LABEL                         PARTLABEL FSUSE% STATE   MODEL
/dev/loop0                 7:0    0         0 loop
...
/dev/loop7                 7:7    0         0 loop
/dev/sda                   8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk                                                                                          running WDC_WD5003ABYX-18WERA0
├─/dev/sda1                8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot          /boot          ext2                                                   60%
├─/dev/sda2                8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─/dev/sda5                8:5    0 465,5G  0 part                               LVM2_member
  ├─/dev/mapper/servamtex2-root
  │                      253:0    0 462,7G  0 lvm  /              /              ext4                                                   50% running
  └─/dev/mapper/servamtex2-swap_1
                         253:2    0   2,8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]         [SWAP]         swap                                                       running
/dev/sdb                   8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk                                                                                          running WDC_WD5002ABYS-18B1B0
├─/dev/sdb2                8:18   0     1K  0 part
└─/dev/sdb5                8:21   0 465,5G  0 part                               LVM2_member
  ├─/dev/mapper/servamtex-root
  │                      253:1    0 462,7G  0 lvm  /servamtex-old /servamtex-old ext4                                                   12% running
  └─/dev/mapper/servamtex-swap_1
                         253:3    0   2,8G  0 lvm                                swap                                                       running
/dev/sdc                   8:32   0   1,8T  0 disk /bu            /bu            ext4                                                   92% running ST2000NM0033-9ZM175
```

------ Edit 2 df used space ----

My question does not relate to interpretation of `df` results but why is there a discrepancy between MOTD system information and df information.  A possible cause is the difference of 5% as pointed out by @muru

Comment: The MOTD is not updated every login, but once per boot or once a day or something like that. If `df` and `du` agree, then the MOTD is simply too old.

Comment: @muru It is possible and I will keep an eye on it  but `bu` is used exsclusively for backup, and changes once a day, in the evening.  The system I am working on is off every evening and restarts in the morning.

Comment: Hmm, actually 1765707476÷1920645740 (from the output of `df`)  is ~92%, so I think this is just the ext4 reserved blocks in action.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [df -h - Used space + Avail Free space is less than the Total size of /home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249387/df-h-used-space-avail-free-space-is-less-than-the-total-size-of-home)

Comment: "My question does not relate to interpretation of df results" ... It does - you're looking at one column of `df` output, which says 97%, and ignoring another column which implies 92% utilisation. The discrepancy in the MOTD output depends on which column you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

The SIZE argument is an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 10*1024).
Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,... (powers of 1000).
Binary prefixes can be used, too: KiB=K, MiB=M, and so on.

check the options there is -h and -H for read diiferent:
-h, --human-readable  print sizes in powers of 1024 (e.g., 1023M)
-H, --si              print sizes in powers of 1000 (e.g., 1.1G)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I added the results of the various forms you give.  No difference in %, and a small difference of 5G used on 1900 G, meaning less than 0.3% of the available total.

Comment: Note `/` includes all storage that resides and is mounted in the filesystem, `/dev/sdc` is most likely not the same, maybe just a portion of it even if the main one. Ponder on the output of `lsblk -ap -o +MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,LABEL,PARTLABEL,FSUSE%,STATE,MODEL`

Comment: @Hannu: good point, I added the results in my question.