# After resize with gparted, still no usable space

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, resize

I extended an ext4 root partition under Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, everything went fine.
However, even after rebooting, the new size is not available.
This is NOT a duplicate as similar questions do not answer the question or do not solve it.
`df -h` shows:

```
/dev/sda4       335G    319G  222M  100% /
```

resize2fs was already done by `gparted` but when anyway running it again it says:

```
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Das Dateisystem ist bereits 89022208 (4k) Blöcke lang. Nichts zu tun!
```

(filesystem is already 89022208 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!

blkid says: (as requested)

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="B628-27FF" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="d982ecb7-50a4-433f-bfc7-97ddd07a6d73"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="SpeedyGonzales" UUID="9C7CAE577CAE2BC8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="b3859d9e-b355-4978-b6f2-67362892af75"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="1729b519-f342-404b-aac7-418e3e6c2079" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Ubuntu" PARTUUID="0add1cbf-90d8-4724-b055-ccda7e6f7474"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Arch" UUID="e67f147e-8416-4553-abc5-3b35c4fdbf37" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Arch" PARTUUID="ecf764ac-0a83-40e8-b2c6-56031d0f735d"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="e9333c6d-68ab-4666-9a40-4c6e1591f104"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="fc0cc4bc-568e-3bbe-a3dc-46fcea0aa5d6" LABEL="HD" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="HD" PARTUUID="f7bf60a4-b3a8-4662-813f-0aad68100a27"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="a7dafe95-71ba-37b2-ab04-1b9895052b0c" LABEL="Recovery HD" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="Recovery HD" PARTUUID="a9a74bb3-2773-4d75-a702-cd5cbf99f925"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2016-06-03-08-15-54-00" LABEL="FRANKREICHST1DVD1" TYPE="udf"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="0ee9290c-5f1a-4e4d-8879-034400cdec7b"
```

/etc/fstab says: (as requested)

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=1729b519-f342-404b-aac7-418e3e6c2079 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,lazytime 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=d24571b0-8d84-43e9-aadb-0e4c2ad6249b none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=B628-27FF  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

This is the tunefs output:

```
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem volume name:   Ubuntu
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          1729b519-f342-404b-aac7-418e3e6c2079
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              22214192
Block count:              89022208
Reserved block count:     3944503
Free blocks:              5091295
Free inodes:              20326541
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1002
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8176
Inode blocks per group:   511
RAID stride:              32715
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Fri Feb 19 16:43:16 2016
Last mount time:          Tue Jul  4 10:48:26 2017
Last write time:          Tue Jul  4 10:48:26 2017
Mount count:              71
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Feb 14 21:59:02 2017
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          2987 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       3292148
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      45015b0b-d746-4270-8283-9c2401206980
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Comment: How big do you think you resized it to?  What does `sudo parted -l` say?

Comment: I thought I resized it to at least 15- 20 GB bigger than before, maybe more.  If you see above, there is a big descrepancy between size and space used, despite the claim that 100 % is used. gparted -l reports a different (bigger) size, but I guess due to different units etc. `4      526GB   891GB   365GB  ext4         Ubuntu
` Full output https://pastebin.com/NAry5rVV

Comment: No. If you look at gparted output, you should see it. It is a gpt disk, but only relatively modern versions of gparted and resize2fs were used and they should be ok with it.

Comment: The difference (335G - 319G) is exactly consistent with ext4's default 5% reserved blocks - see for example [ext4 partition size / free space discrepancies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48488/ext4-partition-size-free-space-discrepancies)

Comment: Thanks for that steeldriver. Anyway, parted and gparted show the proper size at 356 or similar.

Comment: What does `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda4` show?

Comment: @psusi https://pastebin.com/LQ3LeBwE This is the output from tune2fs

Comment: Instead of commenting with a pastebin link, edit your question and add the information there.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be better instead of making the original question longer and longer. Fixed now.