# How to find what causes the mismatch between the reported and the actual used space?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, samba, disk-usage

**1. The setup**

I have a *4 TB WD Red HDD* with one *ext4* partition `/dev/sdb1` mounted on an *Ubuntu 16 LTS Server* under `/DataVolume`. The mounted drive is then served on the network by a samba server.

*Ubuntu Server* is running on a virtual machine hosted by *VMware ESXi 6.5*.

On the *ESXi* the drive is setup as *RDM (Raw Device Mapping)*.

The drive is empty (fresh after recreation of the partition table).

**2. The problem**

`df -T /dev/sdb1` gives the following result:

```
Filesystem     Type  1K-blocks  Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      ext4 3845577736 69648 3650140872   1% /DataVolume
```

*Used space*

Reported: 69648/1024 = **68**, ... MB

Calculated: (3845577736 - 3650140872) / (1024 * 1024) = **186**,... GB

**The calculated used space is much more than the reported value.**

*Free space*

3650140872 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) = **3,39** ... TB

*Capacity*

3845577736 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) = **3,58** ... TB

**3. Research**

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/177127/incorrect-disk-free-space-information-for-a-dfs-client-share) a similar problem is discussed and it is mentioned, that:

> This problem occurs if you mapped a drive to a share that links to a
>   mounted volume by using NTFS volume mount points or by using symbolic
>   links.

*RDM* indeed uses symbolic links, however, no useful info is provided to remedy the problem.

**4. Further details**

The output of `ls -al /DataVolume/` is:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Feb  2 06:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root  4096 Feb  2 12:06 ..
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Feb  2 06:02 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Feb  2 06:05 shares
```

The output of `du -sh /DataVolume/` is:

```
36K     /DataVolume/
```

- Disk usage as reported by *Windows 7* (same as `df -h`):

[image]

- Disk usage as reported by *Ubuntu 17 Desktop* (the used space is more accurate):

[image]

**5. The question**

Does someone know how to find what is consuming this space and causes the mismatch?

EDIT:

The question is indeed very similar to [ext4 partition size / free space discrepancies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48488/ext4-partition-size-free-space-discrepancies). However, if I understand it correctly, the problem there is a smaller reported capacity of the drive. In my case there are 186 GB used in an *empty* drive. I would rather consider it related to the link I've provided, since the size of the used space is close to the size of the used space of the drive holding the simbolic link to the RDM.

Comment: @psusi, thanks for the link! If I understand it correctly, the problem there is a smaller reported capacity of the drive. In my case there are 186 GB used in an empty drive. I would rather relate the cause to the link I've provided, since the size of the used space is close to the size of the used space of the drive holding the simbolic link. In any case I would be glad if you could give me ideas how to approach the problem from this point on.

Comment: @psusi, nope, I am not right. It is not related to the symbolic link. I've changed the filesystem from ext4 to ntfs and reclaimed the space. Now an empty drive is shown as an empty drive. I've upvoted your anser from the link. Thanks a million for pointin my attention to that!

Comment: It's mostly just the way that ext4 reports the statistics.  NTFS has about the same overhead; it just reports differently.

Comment: @psusi, do I understand it correctly: the space is available, just ext4 reports it as used and with root privileges I would be allowed to write to the disk (which doesn't contain system files, just data) when I reach the max capacity minus the used space (186 GB in this case)?

Comment: 5% ( adjustable with `tune2fs` ) of the space is available to root only, so this is subtracted from the available space.  IIRC, The space reported as used is used by internal filesystem metadata.  NTFS has similar metadata, but instead of reporting it as used, it is simply subtracted from the total space.  In that way, ext4 is being more "honest" than NTFS.