# Used 100% disk but the used number shown is wrong

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, disk-usage

My `/dev/sdb2` partition used up all it's space but the `Used` number is less than total `Size` of the partition in large number. I don't know what is happening.
How to check where was my missing 30Gb?
[image]

Here is my inode table
[image]

Comment: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/48488) may be helpful. There are different ways that free space is estimated and reported. A variation of ± 5% is pretty normal. You're at around 3%. In addition to reporting discrepancies, in practice, hard drives need some free space overhead for the file system to function properly. Depending on circumstances this could be between 10% - 20%. Effectively, your disk really is too full and you should try to free up some more space.

Comment: @Nmath tks, let me try remove some more used space

Answer (score 1):

As @Nmath mentioned in the comment: `A variation of ± 5% is pretty normal. You're at around 3%.`
After removing some used space, the amount of `Avail` disk increased and everything was back to normal
[image]