# What's a command line way to find large files/directories to remove and free up space?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

Looking for a series of commands that will show me the largest files on a drive.

Comment: Would something graphical be fine?

Comment: nope, running on command line over ssh.

Comment: What's odd is I have two servers that are running the same thing. One is at 50% disk usage and the other is 99%.  I can't find what's causing this.

Comment: So I'm confused, it says 98% used with du but when I run the gt5 app I get: http://grab.by/9Vv2

Comment: get size of folders: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376125/get-size-of-folders-on-root-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1 
`du -chd1 .`

Comment: sftp connection with Nautilus. Then open the remote location in Disk Usage Analyzer.

Comment: personally I like the answers provided here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728364/why-doesnt-df-show-the-filesystem-disk-space-of-the-path-that-i-give-it

Answer (score 401, accepted):

If you just need to find large files, you can use `find` with the `-size` option. The next command will list all files larger than 10MiB ([not to be confused with 10MB](https://askubuntu.com/q/22102/6969)):

```
find / -size +10M -ls
```

If you want to find files between a certain size, you can combine it with a "size lower than" search. The next command find files between 10MiB and 12MiB:

```
find / -size +10M -size -12M -ls
```

---

`apt-cache search 'disk usage'` lists some programs available for disk usage analysis. One application that looks very promising is `gt5`.

From the package description:

> Years have passed and disks have become larger and larger, but even on this incredibly huge harddisk era, the space seems to disappear over time. This small and effective programs provides more convenient listing than the default du(1). It displays what has happened since last run and displays dir size and the total percentage. It is possible to navigate and ascend to directories by using cursor-keys with text based browser (links, elinks, lynx etc.)

[image: Screenshot of gt5]

On the "related packages" section of [gt5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/gt5), I found `ncdu`. From its package description:

> Ncdu is a ncurses-based du viewer. It provides a fast and easy-to-use interface through famous du utility. It allows to browse through the directories and show percentages of disk usage with ncurses library.

[image: Screenshot of ncdu]

Comment: ncdu is very quick and just what i needed, thanks! I've tried gt5 too, but just canceled it because it was "thinking" too long w/o any feedback

Comment: Holy crap, ncdu is amazing, thank you for sharing your findings!

Comment: I would love if **ncdu** was pointed out stronger. I need it once in a while and I can't remember the name.

Comment: Enough of remembering commands thanks to ncdu :)

Comment: Can you add the `-h` option (or other ones) to the `ls` somehow?

Comment: @matt Nope, the output format for the `-ls` output is hardcoded (see the source code for [`pred_fls`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/pred.c?h=v4.7.0#n443) and [list_file](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/listfile.c?h=v4.7.0#n304) functions). You could try to approximate the output using the `-printf` option, post-process the output with awk, or use something like `find ... -type f -exec ls -ldh {} \; | column -t`

Comment: for explaining MiB vs MB it is bad practice to give a link. Not only does it context switch but it make the answer not self contained + if the link changes, dies etc it makes your answer partially useless. I strongly suggest to write what you had in mind even if it's just 1 sentence summary.

Answer (score 78):

My favorite solution uses a mix from several of these good answers.

```
du -aBM 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -n 50 | more
```

`du` arguments:

- `-a` for "all" files and directories. Leave it off for just directories
- `-BM` to output the sizes in megabyte (M) block sizes (B)
- `2>/dev/null` - exclude "permission denied" error messages (thanks @Oli)

`sort` arguments:

- `-n` for "numeric"
- `-r` for "reverse" (biggest to smallest)

`head` arguments:

- `-n 50` for the just top 50 results.
- Leave off `more` if using a smaller number

Note: Prefix with `sudo` to include directories that your account does not have permission to access.

Example showing top 10 biggest files and directories in /var (including grand total).

```
cd /var
sudo du -aBM 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -n 10
7555M   .
6794M   ./lib
5902M   ./lib/mysql
3987M   ./lib/mysql/my_database_dir
1825M   ./lib/mysql/my_database_dir/a_big_table.ibd
997M    ./lib/mysql/my_database_dir/another_big_table.ibd
657M    ./log
629M    ./log/apache2
587M    ./log/apache2/ssl_access.log
273M    ./cache
```

Comment: Tanx for this Enterprise solution. I just want to complete this by adding 'cd /' before running the command : 'cd /;sudo du -aBM 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -n 10 > sizelog.txt'

Answer (score 39):

I just use a combination of `du` and `sort`.

```
sudo du -sx /* 2>/dev/null | sort -n

0   /cdrom
0   /initrd.img
0   /lib64
0   /proc
0   /sys
0   /vmlinuz
4   /lost+found
4   /mnt
4   /nonexistent
4   /selinux
8   /export
36  /media
56  /scratchbox
200 /srv
804 /dev
4884    /root
8052    /bin
8600    /tmp
9136    /sbin
11888   /lib32
23100   /etc
66480   /boot
501072  /web
514516  /lib
984492  /opt
3503984 /var
7956192 /usr
74235656    /home
```

Then it's a case of **rinse and repeat**. Target the subdirectories you think are too big, run the command for them and you find out what's causing the problem.

Note: I use `du`'s `-x` flag to keep things limited to one filesystem (I have quite a complicated arrangement of cross-mounted things between SSD and RAID5).

Note 2: `2>/dev/null` redirects any error messages into oblivion. If they don't bother you, it's not obligatory.

Comment: When I run this command du descends into child directories. From the `du` man page: "Summarize disk usage of each FILE, recursively for directories."

Answer (score 18):

To display the biggest top-20 directories (recursively) in the current folder, use the following one-liner:

```
du -ah . | sort -rh | head -20
```

or (more Unix oriented):

```
du -a . | sort -rn | head -20
```

For the top-20 biggest files in the current directory (recursively):

```
ls -1Rs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -nr | head -n20
```

or with human readable sizes:

```
ls -1Rhs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -hr | head -n20
```

> Please note that `-h` is available for GNU `sort` only, so to make it work on OSX/BSD properly, you've to install it from `coreutils`. Then add its folder into your `PATH`.

So these aliases are useful to have in your *rc* files (every time when you need it):

```
alias big='du -ah . | sort -rh | head -20'
alias big-files='ls -1Rhs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -hr | head -n20'
```

Answer (score 10):

qbi's answer is correct but it will be very slow when there are a lot of files since it will start a new ls process for each item.

a much faster version using find without spawning child processes would be to use printf to print the size in bytes (%s) and the path (%p)

`find "$directory" -type f -printf "%s - %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n $num_entries`

Comment: Confirm that this is much faster

Answer (score 10):

A great, user-friendly tool referenced in the answer to a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space) is `NCurses Disk Usage` tool:

```
sudo ncdu /
```

Comment: Well, starting at the root of the filesystem was exactly the opposite of pointless to me. It allowed me to identify the most important places to target for space saving across the whole filesystem. Regardless, you can use the mentioned to start at any directory. Check out the docs for that tool. But, as requested, here is the link to the [source answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/279335).

Answer (score 9):

This seems like the perfect application for `find`:

```
find $DIRECTORY -type f -exec ls -s {} \; | sort -n | tail -n 5
```

This command will find all files in directory `$DIRECTORY` and execute `ls -s` on them. The last command prints the allocated size of a file plus the filename. The result is sorted numerically and and the last five entries are shown. So as result you'll see the largest 5 files in `$DIRETORY` or any subdirectory. If you enter `tail -n 1` you'll see only the largest file.

Furthermore you can play around a lot with `find`. For instance you can look for files which are younger than *n* days (`-ctime -n`) or which belong to special users (`-user johndoe`).

Answer (score 6):

When I need make more free space on servers I use this command. It find all files bigger then 50 MB and "du -h" make better list of files and "sort -n" after pipe make list numericcaly sorted by file size.

```
find / -size +50M -type f -exec du -h {} \; | sort -n
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Baobab, it gives you a graphical overview of files and folders, you can see where the real space hogs are and delete them with one click
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab

Comment: In this particular question, the OP prefers a command line method. See the comments to the question. I'll edit the question as well.

Comment: Amazing utility if you have access to GUI

Answer (score 1):

To find all GB files for instance I would use du and grep, though the other methods mentioned here seem great as well.

```
du -h -a /dir | grep "[0-9]G\b"
```

You can also get fancy with the --except option that du has.

Answer (score 0):

You could also sort files by size:

```
find . -type f -exec du -h {} \; | sort -k1 -h
```

It finds only files and executes `du -h` for every file, which shows the size of the file. Lastly, we sort the output of `find`/`du` according to the first column (in human readable format).

The last printed file is the largest one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command to see the largest files while skipping the directories:

```
sudo find / -type f -printf “%s\t%p\n” | sort -n | tail -1
find $HOME -type f -printf ‘%s %p\n’ | sort -nr | head -10
```

To find all files that are larger than 100MiB (this is not 100MB, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/22102/) if you are confused):

```
find / -size +100M -ls
```

the command below will  display the largest 5 files in the folder `$DIRECTORY`:

```
find $DIRECTORY -type f -exec ls -s {} \; | sort -n | tail -n 5
```

USING `du` :
The command below which uses du, display the directories with the 20 largest sizes in the home working folder:

```
sudo du -a /home | sort -n -r | head -n 20
```

Now in order now to display the largest directories/files including sub-folders, run:

```
du -Sh | sort -rh | head -n 10
```

Using `ls`:

To list the 5 top largest files in the /bin directory , issue the command below:

```
ls -lSh /bin | head -5
```

You can also use the Disk Usage Analyzer or [Baobao](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/) as shown [here](https://net2.com/how-to-find-the-largest-files-on-ubuntu/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer here is useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728364/why-doesnt-df-show-the-filesystem-disk-space-of-the-path-that-i-give-it/728373#728373

but the short summary is TLDR:

```
For space usage do:
df -h path2inode
above for systemfile usage

du -hs path2inode
du -hs ~ | grep data | head -5
du -hs ~ | sort rh | head -5
above for specific inode. Might be slow. 

To see space your using for specific files & total limit run both commands.
```