# 0 bytes of free space in home directory

Tags: filesystem, home-directory

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Latitude E4300 laptop. Also I'm a complete Noob on Ubuntu. Booting is without problems, and I can access the the login screen with a working graphical background.

But after entering the correct password I'm thrown back to the login screen. There is only a flashing Error shown for a timespan of <1 second. I can only read the first line before being thrown back to the login screen. It reads: `pipe broken`.

I can however access the Guest account. Upon doing so I get an error message that says:

```
There is 0 bytes of free space  in the drive "home".
```

Entering `df -h` confirms this error message:

```
Filesystem: dev/sda5 Size: 84G available: 80G  free: 0 usage: 100% mounted in: /home
Filesystem: home/veronika/.Private Size: 84G available: 80G  free: 0 usage: 100% mounted in: /home/veronika
```

So, what I'm basically asking is advise on how to delete files from the home directory from the console.

What I did as of now to fix the problem:

⠀• Emptying the Trash
⠀• Using BleachBit (failed)
⠀• Removing .Xauthority
⠀• Reinstalling Nvidia driver

None of these measures had any success.

I'd be really grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: You can use this `find /home/veronika/ -type f -exec ls -s {} \; | sort -n | tail -n 5`  http://askubuntu.com/questions/36111/whats-a-command-line-way-to-find-large-files-directories-to-remove-and-free-up to find the largest files in /home Analyse the largest 5 and see if you can removed them.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked fine for me. I was able to remove 2 GB of old error logs. After that the login worked completly fine.

Comment: Can you please make that edit an answer? You can then accept it and everyone knows it works!

Comment: well, I tried that. But as it happens, you can't answer your own question with less than 10 reputation points. sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Rinzwind!

Used this command to find the biggest files:

```
find /home/veronika/ -type f -exec ls -s {} \; | sort -n | tail -n 5
```

It took a few minutes for the files to be listed.

After that I just removed the biggest file in the list, which in my case happened to be error-logs.old