# Displaying all ‘.sh’ files with size more than 5kb

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to list all the files with .sh extension and size greater than 5kb with the same directory.
what I know is how to list all files with a specific size by:

```
find . -size +5k -exec ls -l {} \+
```

and how to list all the files with specific extension by:

```
ls *.sh
```

what do I need to know is how to do both simultaneously?

Comment: related: [What's a command line way to find large files/directories to remove and free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36111/507051)

Comment: You may also want to read [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`find` has a `-name` option to perform a test on the file name, e.g. to list every `f`ile with an `.sh` extension:

```bsh
find -type f -name "*.sh"
```

Use `-iname` instead if you want it to be case-insensitive, e.g. also find `.Sh` or `.SH`. You can simply combine this with `-size`:

```bsh
find -type f -name "*.sh" -size +5k
```

`find` also has an `-ls` option to display file stats, while your `-exec` approach is totally OK it may be faster and is much easier to type:

```bsh
find -type f -name "*.sh" -size +5k -ls
```