# Not enough space on parition mounted at /

Tags: 16.04, disk, cuda, df

I'm trying to install cuda toolkit:

```
sudo sh cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux.run --silent --toolkit --toolkitpath=/usr/local/cuda-10.0
Not enough space on parition mounted at /.
Need 3391705088 bytes.

Disk space check has failed. Installation cannot continue.
```

But seems I have less free space that needed.

How can I check if have sufficient disk space?

`df -h` show me:

```
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                   16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                 3.2G  331M  2.9G  11% /run
/dev/sde3                              39G   32G  4.9G  87% /
tmpfs                                  16G   80K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                 5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                  16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sde4                             167G   99G   61G  63% /home
/dev/mapper/isw_cifjedgigg_Volume1p1  1.8T  1.5T  268G  85% /data
/dev/sdb1                             470G  195G  251G  44% /data/ssd
cgmfs                                 100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                                 3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1009
tmpfs                                 3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1002
```

Is `/dev/sde3` low on space? How to check what consume most of the space?

**Update:**

I'm more looking toward CUDA related answer, because I was able to install several version of CUDA several times and then even deleting older versions of CUDA from `/usr/local` don't help, so I suspect some 'caches' after CUDA installation is still in the system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a command line way to find large files/directories to remove and free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36111/whats-a-command-line-way-to-find-large-files-directories-to-remove-and-free-up). I see a / issue more than a /boot issue here.

Comment: @user535733 As '/boot' is not mounted separatly, it should be under '/'

Comment: @CharlesGreen What about `/usr/local` it's not related to `/`?  because deleting older cuda versions from `/usr/local/cuda` not helped to free space.

Comment: @mrgloom My own script for finding huge directories is this:  `sudo du -ahx -d 1 . | sort -rh | head -20` - start with `cd /`, run the script (takes a minute the first time) and then look into directories which seem overly large.  My script will not cross disk boundaries, and as such will not look at `/data`, `/data/ssd`, and `/home` on your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the individual file/directory disk usage by running the `du -sh *` command in the / directory... It can take a considerable amount of time because it recursively scans the directory structure.... What you have here is a single / partition which means that your boot/var/ reside inside /.... this isn't ideal.... First of all check If there are too many kernels in the /boot directory, keep the latest two and remove the rest (very carefully).... Also check if any log files in /var are using too much space... clear those files if they aren't important