# The 'ls -lS' command shows weird folders sizes

Tags: files, ls

My laptop says the disk is full, so I'm trying to make some space by removing some files. But the `ls` output doesn't make sense for me. The `Downloads` directory, in reality, is empty... I guess the issue is elsewhere, but I have no idea of how to start solving the problem.

The problem persists after the new system installation.

`ls -lSh` output:

```
maria@maria-Vostro-3360:/media/maria/2845d360-0b89-46c8-97ff-dc5e9862949e          /home/maria$ ls -lSh  
total 196K
drwxr-xr-x  2 maria maria  28K Sep 30 14:59  Downloads
-rw-rw-r--  1 maria maria  24K Sep 16  2017  missfont.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 maria maria  17K Nov 25  2017 'zmiany w ustawie o promocji.odt'
-rw-rw-r--  1 maria maria  16K Jan 30  2017  testdisk.log
-rw-r-----  1 root  root   16K Feb 28  2017  hp-check.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 maria maria  12K Jun  3  2018 'kid silk może.odt'
-rw-r--r--  1 maria maria 8,8K Oct 30  2016  examples.desktop
-rw-rw-r--  1 maria maria 6,9K Sep 27  2017 'Masza pismo wyjaśniajace.docx'
drwxr-xr-x  9 maria maria 4,0K Aug 26  2018  Books
drwxr-xr-x 21 maria maria 4,0K Sep 29 15:10  Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 maria maria 4,0K Sep 23 15:17  Documents
drwxr-xr-x  4 maria maria 4,0K Dec 10  2016  install-tl-20161106
drwxr-xr-x  2 maria maria 4,0K Aug 26  2018  Manuals
drwxr-xr-x 75 maria maria 4,0K Jul  8  2018  Music
drwxr-xr-x 13 maria maria 4,0K Apr  1 15:02  Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  5 maria maria 4,0K Aug 26  2018  Praca
drwxr-xr-x  2 maria maria 4,0K Oct 30  2016  Public
drwxrwxr-x  2 maria maria 4,0K Jul 16  2018  pyt
drwxr-xr-x  6 maria maria 4,0K Nov  3  2018  snap
drwxr-xr-x  2 maria maria 4,0K Oct 30  2016  Templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 maria maria 4,0K Apr  5 12:54  Videos
drwxrwxr-x  3 maria maria 4,0K Dec 11  2016 'VirtualBox VMs'
drwxr-xr-x  2 maria maria 4,0K Aug 26  2018  Wspólnota
```

`df` output:

```
maria@maria-Vostro-3360:/media/maria/2845d360-0b89-46c8-97ff-dc5e9862949e/home/maria/Downloads$ df
Filesystem                  1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          1913424         0   1913424   0% /dev
tmpfs                          388988      1352    387636   1% /run
/dev/sdb1                   960378852 260817848 650706632  29% /
tmpfs                         1944928     36364   1908564   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         1944928         0   1944928   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                          388984        28    388956   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 304884768 285483308   3844444  99% /media/maria/2845d360-0b89-46c8-97ff-dc5e9862949e
```

UPDATE -

'du' output on '/Downloads':

```
maria@maria-Vostro-3360:/media/maria/2845d360-0b89-46c8-97ff-dc5e9862949e/home/maria$ du -hs /media/maria/2845d360-0b89-46c8-97ff-dc5e9862949e/home/maria/Downloads/
56K /media/maria/2845d360-0b89-46c8-97ff-dc5e9862949e/home/maria/Downloads/
```

Content of the directory:

```
maria@maria-Vostro-3360:/media/maria/2845d360-0b89-46c8-97ff-dc5e9862949e/home/maria$ ls -a /media/maria/2845d360-0b89-46c8-97ff-dc5e9862949e/home/maria/Downloads/
 .
 ..
'.~lock.Abused No More_MODENA_Agenda.docx#'
'.~lock.IARS PR_YEIP_notatka prasowa pl.docx#'
'.~lock.Interviews_SELEX II_reporting template.docx#'
'.~lock.ogloszenie_o_zatrudnieniu_nr 13b_ASYSTENT MIĘDZYKULTUROWY_ARAB_ENG.docx#'
'.~lock.Oświadczenie o zamiarze powierzenia wykonywania pracy obywatelowi Republiki Armenii, Białorusi, Gruzji, Mołdowy, Federacji Rosyjskiej lub Ukrainy.doc#'
'.~lock.PL_S_1_reporting template.docx#'
'.~lock.wartość sprzedaży alkoholu 2015 i 2016.docx#'
```

'du' output on '/dev/mapper

```
maria@maria-Vostro-3360:/dev/mapper$ du -skh *
0   control
0   luks-316afb25-f21a-4171-978b-87706fd85a74
0   ubuntu--vg-root
0   ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

Comment: Looks normal to me. `ls` does NOT return the size of the entire directory-with-contents. Use `du` for that.

Comment: Your `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` directory is going out of space. Go to that directory and run `du -skh *`

Comment: @PrinceKumarBarnwal - under update

Comment: @user535733 under update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a command line way to find large files/directories to remove and free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36111/whats-a-command-line-way-to-find-large-files-directories-to-remove-and-free-up)

Answer (score 1):

In Linux filesystems the directories are inodes like regular files, but they contain references to other files (file names, in particular). So their disk size is roughly proportional to the number of entries they point to (child files/directories). However when you erase child files and directories the space is not always reclaimed, so your output above is just showing you how big your `Downloads` directory inode had to grow once to contain the data for a few hundred files.