# Ubuntu showing low disk space on file system root

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, syslinux

I have installed Ubuntu-20.04 a couple of months ago (not VM).
But now it is showing  this “low disk space” message.

I am very new to Ubuntu. I do not know what to do now.

I also use Windows 10 for other works.

Can I increase partition size without  reinstalling Ubuntu? Or what should I do now?

And since I am a beginner, I might have forgotten to mention any  important  details. Please let me know if I have.

```
$ df -h
```

[image: df -h output]

```
 $ df -ih
```

[image: df -ih output]

Comment: Can you modify your question please, and include the outputs of two commands:  `df -h` and `df -ih`

Comment: @CharlesGreen -modified.

Comment: Your root partition (/) is full. Use https://askubuntu.com/questions/36111/whats-a-command-line-way-to-find-large-files-directories-to-remove-and-free-up to find out which files are taking up the most space. Also check the size of /var/log/syslog - it it's big, then your logs are trying to tell you about a problem, and out-of-space is merely a symptom.

Comment: Whilst Lubuntu doesn't have a minimum disk space suggestion, Ubuntu Desktop has suggested 25GB (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) since before Ubuntu 17.10 was released.  Many users can happily live on less space, but you need to maintain your system more with less disk space (ie. upgrade very often as they need space to download, install etc), clean up often, be careful with added applications etc.  Yes you can grow system partition size (doing it from *live* system expanding using space next to the partition)

Comment: Above comments are great - your root disk is too small.  You may be able to fix this by booting from USB, and using Gparted to resize the disks.

Comment: Additional comment - thanks for the update to the question.  For future use, please do not post pictures.  Instead copy/paste the text into your question - there are ways to format this so that it's easy for someone like me to scroll through.