# Low disk space on Filesystem root

Tags: disk-usage

I am having this popup. I have seen others having the same issue but am not sure how to deal with it, since each solution was different. Can someone suggest what to do here?

I'd like to list the output from my df command

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3883176         0   3883176   0% /dev
tmpfs             784180      2560    781620   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3 241655276 227974592   1335548 100% /
tmpfs            3920888    499256   3421632  13% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            3920888         0   3920888   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1    243864     84488    159376  35% /boot/efi
```

Comment: Your disk is full. Ask yourself: "*Why is it full?*" The two most common issues are 1) The user has been downloading lots of movies (or other big data files), or 2) The /var/log/syslog file has grown massively, logging some underlying problem over and over and over. There are other less-common possibilities.

Comment: I removed a few lines that are not related to the full disk Makes it better readable ;-) And I agree with @user535733 check home for large video files (as you do not have a separate /home)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a command line way to find large files/directories to remove and free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36111/whats-a-command-line-way-to-find-large-files-directories-to-remove-and-free-up)