# How do I free spaces while I have 6 packages that are not upgraded

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.10

I’m having a big problem with my computer, I’m trying to free spaces to remove packages I don’t need. I tried everything I find on how to fix this problem, but they don’t work.

I kept having this error saying:

“You don’t have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/“

But I got “0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded”

I don’t know what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome. Please let's focus on one thing at a time - that you're out of disk space. Take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36111/whats-a-command-line-way-to-find-large-files-directories-to-remove-and-free-up) to find why your disk is full.

Comment: Also, you should probably include the exact commands and output that you run for troubleshooting purposes. Also include output of `df -h` to list mounts, and also `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null | sort -hr` to view largest directories in `/`.

Comment: On most systems, packages take up very little space, and trying to remove packages to free space is often an inefficient use of your time and effort: You may free up 100MB of packages, but you missed the 25GB of movies or runaway logs or other low-hanging fruit. Look at other users of your storage space using `baobab`, `du`, and `df`. Look up how to use those tools to discover the biggest storage-hogs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with `sudo apt-get clean`, which will remove all unneeded .deb files from `/var/cache/apt/archives` and that may be enough space to uninstall unneeded packages to free up even more space.

You can also empty your trash and delete other files you don't need.

Additionally Ubuntu comes with a program called "Disk Usage Analyzer" (`baobab` in the terminal), I believe, which can help you find large files and folders you maybe didn't even remember having.