# ffmpeg: how to bulk-compress videos into a subfolder, but only those >1Mb?

Tags: ffmpeg, anki

Using [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) desktop and AnkiDroid to develop a LSF (French Sign Language) learning deck, I edit cards with written word on front card, signed word in .mp4 on back card.

With a ~10k cards right now, I would like to reduce size of the .mp4 media files.
For a month or two, when I create a new card, just after having added a video to this card with AnkiDroid, I reduce its size entering this custom command in Termux:

```
tsu ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ichi2.anki/files/AnkiDroid/collection.media/name_of_the_video_file.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 40
```

But for all the other I added before, I would like to  "bulk"-aplly this command to all the .mp4 files of this folder, but only those weighting more than 1Mb.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Or even better if it is even possible: apply it only to videos weighting more than 300kb per second :)

Comment: The comments are our channel for asking you for certifications. Please edit your question target than adding new information in comments.

Comment: Read [this question and all it's answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36111/whats-a-command-line-way-to-find-large-files-directories-to-remove-and-free-up) for how to find files of size > 1MB. Then pipe the output of that command into your command to compress those files.