# Install Problem - Install Now Button doesn't bring up the next window

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, live-usb, disk, drive

I've noticed a number of people were having an issue with the install now button being greyed out during the installation type stage of installing. However, my problem is not that it is greyed out. I am able to click the button and when I do, it responds and a loading thing replaces my cursor. After a couple seconds the cursor returns to normal and nothing happens. I'm still looking at the select drive screen.
If I hit install now again, it seems to act as the back button, taking me to the screen which I selected erase disk on.

I'm trying to install from a live usb which I made on a windows desktop using the program rufus., which passed disk check at the start of the process. I did not check to be sure the hash of the ISO was correct.

Also, I originally had Windows 7 on this laptop (no longer installed) And now have Fedora still installed which I would like to overwrite with Ubuntu.) The screen which asks if I want to erase the disk, etc. states that "This computer currently has no detected operating systems."

Comment: Is that what's causing the problem? I would rather overwrite Fedora.

Comment: What would I do with that option to basically do the equivalent of the erase option? I'm curious if just taking that path through the installation might avoid my problem.

Comment: I didn't verify that no, but I should mention I made the usb installer on a windows desktop using the program rufus. Also I'm using the current ubuntu LTS iso (16.04)

Comment: If I knew for certain that you had verified the integrity of the iso I could predict with a high level of certainty what would happen. Yes you should mention that. Please [edit] that into your question as it may be relevant.

Comment: I've edited your post in an attempt to provide some clarity.  Please review it carefully and If I've inadvertently made an incorrect change, please [edit] it to accuracy. Thank you for helping us help you! :-)

Comment: Sorry about the delay but I checked that the md5 hash matched and it does. I even redownloaded the iso and started the process over again to get the same result.

Comment: Actually not sure what I've done but I've somehow managed to break my 16gb usb stick, just connected back to my windows pc and it reports only having a maximum storage of 5.71 mb.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you've done either. A hardware problem with the stick could have easily been the source of your problem.

Comment: Nevermind I was being stupid. I assume it showed up that way because when I reformatted the usb with the ubuntu iso the second time I selected the format as dd image option in rufus. When I loaded the usb into rufus again it still shows 16gb, I'm now reformatting as iso like the first time. And also using rufus' check device for bad blocks function.

Comment: You could check it with `gparted if you can still boot try Ubuntu from it. Windows can't be trusted to recognize Linux file systems.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I deleted all the fedora partitions using gparted, then tried to start the installation again and it worked.
Fedora must have been doing something to prevent being overwritten, I guess.

Thanks for the help Elder.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario is that the ISO you used to create the installation media is corrupted. You can confirm this by checking the iso file you downloaded against the list [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/MD5SUMS) using any of the methods listed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788#503788).

If you still have issues after insuring that you have a good iso, you may have a hardware problem with the [installation media](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737473/check-real-size-of-usb-thumb-drive), [RAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/591502) or [target media](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10/528077#528077).

Note Flash drives have a limited lifespan measured in write cycles and can fail after between 10,000 to 100,000 write/erase cycles, depending on the memory technology used.

Note Source:

http://www.flashbay.com/blog/usb-life-expectancy

Comment: Sorry about the delay but I checked that the md5 hash matched and it does. I even redownloaded the iso and started the process over again to get the same result.

Comment: the md5 matched on the original copy or on the redownloaded copy that you started over with and got the same result? Pardon my confusion.

Comment: it matched on both