# Bought fake USB thumb drive from Aliexpress. Seller says it isn't fake. How to generate definitive evidence?

Tags: hardware, usb-drive, hardware-test

I bought an USB thumb drive of 64 GB, to check its size I did as the answer in the link bellow instructs:

[Check real size of USB thumb drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737473/check-real-size-of-usb-thumb-drive)

Here's an image from my terminal executing the commands:

[My terminal output (red rectangle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyzK6.png)

The `f3probe` indicates an actual size of 32 GB.

The seller said that this is incorrect and uploaded an image doing a counter proof:

[Seller's evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iz1y.png)

Showing the size of 61 GB.

Are any of those tests reliable?

If yes, which is right?

If my test is the right one, it is enough evidence to win a dispute in Aliexpress? Case it's not, which evidence should I add?

Comment: This isn't really about Ubuntu or hardware compatibility with Ubuntu, so I've voted to close it as off topic (since it has nothing to do with Ubuntu). But you're probably not going to get very far arguing the issue with a seller on AliExpress, which is probably some random desk jockey that just does "support" for their posting on Ali. It's clearly a counterfeit drive, and the seller isn't doing anything to help, so you should escalate to AliExpress itself, or your credit card if that's also ineffective.

Comment: But you and the seller aren't testing the same unique USB thumb drive correct? Also you don't mention the make and model number of the unit. Finally the question is off topic for this website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware purchase issues.

Comment: I bought a fake USB outside an electronics store in Delhi, for an incredibly good price. Authentic sealed packaging and everything. It was hollow inside. I have kept it as a reminder. If it sounds too good to be true...